# Java modifying run(), by adding a loop and removing the call to display()!

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

SO I am having much difficulty with the Java code, I am supposed is to modify ContactList.java so that it loops prompting the user for an integer key. If the key is non-negative, search the array for a Person with that key. If the Person is found, display the Person. If the Person is not found, display a message to that effect. If the user enters a negative key, the program should terminate. But not sure where to implement the while Loop. Also Currently run() throws IOException. Im trying change run() so that it catches IOException, and if an exception is caught, display a descriptive message and terminate.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactList {

    private Person[] theList;
    private int n;            // the number of Persons in theList

    // Returns a Scanner associated with a specific text-based URL
    // online.
    private Scanner makeScanner() throws IOException {
        final String source = 
          "http://userpages.umbc.edu/~jmartens/courses/is247/hw/05/05.txt";
        final URL src = new URL(source);
        return new Scanner(src.openStream());
    } // makeScanner()


    // Return a Person instance based upon data read from the given
    // Scanner.
    private Person getPerson(final Scanner in) throws FileFormatException {
        if (!in.hasNextLine())
          return null;

        String line = in.nextLine().trim();
        int key = Integer.parseInt(line);
        String name = in.nextLine().trim();
        String mail = in.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
        if (in.hasNextLine()) {
          String empty = in.nextLine().trim(); // skip blank line
          if (empty.length() > 0)
            throw new FileFormatException("missing blank line");
        } // if

        return new Person(key, name, mail);
    } // getPerson()


    // Display the array contents.
    private void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
          System.out.println(theList[i]);
    } // display()


    // Example code to display the contents of the contact list file.
    private void run() throws IOException {
        theList = new Person[1024];
        Scanner in = makeScanner();

        int index = 0; 
        Person p = getPerson(in);
        while (p != null) {
          theList[index++] = p;
          p = getPerson(in);
        }
        n = index;

        display();
    } // run()


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ContactList cl = new ContactList();
        cl.run();
    } // main()

} // class ContactList
```

Comment: If this is homework, as it appears, please label it as such.

Comment: Please change your title to something more meaningful. It will increase your chances of getting useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about try/catch?

```
private void run() {
    try {
        // Loop, etc.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place it once the whole list is read in the `run()` method:

```
  private void run() throws IOException {
    theList = new Person[1024];
    Scanner in = makeScanner();

    int index = 0; 
    Person p = getPerson(in);
    while (p != null) {
      theList[index++] = p;
      p = getPerson(in);
    }
    n = index;

    display();

    int key = 0;
    do {
      System.out.print("Enter a key: ");
      try {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        key = userInput.nextInt();
      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("> Invalid key");
        continue;
      }

      Person found = search(key);
      if (found == null)
        System.out.println("> Person not found");
      else
        System.out.println("> Person found => " + found);
    } while(key >= 0);
  } // run()
```

The `search` method is a simple loop comparing the id of each `Person` in the list with the provided key.

For the `run` method not throwing `IOException`, follow *pamphlet*'s answer.